# Gnome Tracker integration with emacs

Tags: search, docview, pdf-tools

I use Gnome Tracker quite a bit and am led to wonder whether there is currently any way to use Tracker from within emacs? That is to say; searching for files indexed by Tracker, within emacs (and consequently reading them with pdf-tools or docview). It would be one less reason to fire up the Tracker Desktop Search interface.

[ https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker ]

Comment: Does it come with a command line interface? In this case, it should be relatively straight forward to write a little emacs interface. I did the same for KDE's Baloo using helm: https://github.com/malb/emacs.d/blob/master/malb.org#kde-desktop-search-with-baloo

Comment: @MartinR.Albrecht, yes it does have a fairly good command line interface; the CLI is better than the GUI in a sense and what you have done there for Baloo is what I am looking for Tracker. Thanks for the nice pointer; I will try to put together something useful!

Comment: I would love to see what you've come up with @VishalBelsare. THis would be great for me to have too!

Comment: @Matt just seeing your comment. I did not do much with Martin's suggestion, with the exception of a bare bones function which calls tracker. I will post that as an answer.

Comment: @Matt, please see the function 'tracker-dbus-async'. While a lot more could be done, this is a little more useful than before. I want to add the FTS snippets in the display also, but I don't know enough to integrate the that information in a dired buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at Martin's link to using baloo under KDE, the following function calls tracker's sparql query and shows the  results in a new frame. A lot more needs to be done and could be added to make this really useful. The results are shown in a file URI format, and find-file-at-point works to open the documents in DocView mode. I use this mainly to use full-text search over a collection of PDF articles (and some ODT/DOCX files). More information could be displayed by modifying the sparql query. I'd love to add something akin to org-mode's hyperlink file display, i.e. return the list of files displaying just the filename and hiding the file URI in the hyperlink - would save column space.

```
;;
    (defun tracker-sparql (sparql-query)
      (start-process "tracker-sparql" "tracker-sparql" "tracker" "sparql" "-q" sparql-query)
      (switch-to-buffer-other-frame "tracker-sparql")
      )

    (defun tracker (search-term)
      (interactive "sFulltext Search String: ")
      (tracker-sparql (concat "SELECT nie:url(?f) WHERE { ?f fts:match '"
                  search-term
                  "' }")
              )
      )


(require 'dbus)

(defun tracker-dbus-async (search-terms)

  (interactive "sFulltext Search String: ")  
  ;; mapcar 'car --> mapcar 'url-file-truename --> dired cons
  (defun tracker-results-process (search-terms results)
    (dired (cons
        (concat "Tracker Search: " search-terms)
        (mapcar (lambda (x) (url-file-truename (car x))) results)
        ))
    )

  (fset 'tracker-results-process-fix-search-terms
    (apply-partially 'tracker-results-process search-terms))

  (let ((search-query (concat "SELECT nie:url(?f) WHERE { 
                   ?f a nfo:Document . ?f fts:match '" search-terms "'
                   } ORDER BY 
                   DESC (fts:rank(?f))")))
    ;; search-query
    (dbus-call-method-asynchronously
                :session "org.freedesktop.Tracker1"
                "/org/freedesktop/Tracker1/Resources"
                "org.freedesktop.Tracker1.Resources"
                "SparqlQuery"
                'tracker-results-process-fix-search-terms
                search-query
                )
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Some years ago I wrote a dired-based interface to tracker results. It's not polished, but in case it is of any use, you can find the code here:
https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Tracker