# Adding another column of information to dired (text snippets by Gnome Tracker)

Tags: dired

I have a small Emacs Lisp function which calls Gnome Tracker's FTS Search via D-Bus and display results in a dired buffer.

[ https://gist.github.com/vishalbelsare/4f78722856a6bca7faf1f73353892025 ]

I pass the array (list) of filepaths (file URIs) returned by Gnome Tracker to emacs dired, to make inspection easier i.e. using the set of functions which dired provides.

One thing I miss in this setup is that Gnome Tracker can also return snippets of the text, with a few words before and after   the matching terms. Say I search for the string 'emacs lisp', then the snippets would show for each file 'n' words before the searched string and 'n' words after. It helps in seeing whether the result is relevant beyond simple matching.

[ https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker/Documentation/Examples/SPARQL/FTS ]

Now to come to the question :
**Can another column of information be added to dired to also show the text snippets returned by Gnome Tracker?**

p.s: original question about using Gnome Tracker from Emacs : [ [Gnome Tracker integration with emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/32443/14450) ]