# Custom comment in dired

Tags: dired

I create around 50 folders in a day. I use dired. I need to add custom comments such as New (N), old (o) and Review (R) to analyse my days work. Is adding the comments in dired possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/37760/105.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are asking whether it is possible to add your own column, whose value for a given file or directory would be an annotation ("comment", tag, etc.) associated with that file or directory.

The answer is no.  You can program your own Dired-like listings that do something like that, but it's not something offered by Dired.

Essentially, Dired uses the output of an `ls` command.  If your `ls` command can print such an additional file attribute (and you have assigned values for that attribute to files) then great.  If not then plain Dired, using `ls` is not going to support this.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. But do we have any other way to put tag to folders?

Comment: If you use [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) then you can tag a file or directory with arbitrary [tags](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#BookmarkTags), as an [*autofile* bookmark](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#AutofileBookmarks). This gives you something similar to what you're asking about, but in a different form.